# How to add list datatype in Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

This is how my model.py looks like. The third field (label) should contain more than one value (as a news post can have more than one label) like a list. How to achieve that?

```
    from django.db import 

    class News(models.Model)
        heading=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        post_date=models.DateTimeField('Date Posted')
        labels=models.???
```

Comment: Read up on `ManyToMany` field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django not provide default list field, so that you have to create your own  list field from inherit TextField,  I am posting one of the example code have a look.

```
class ListField(models.TextField, metaclass=models.SubfieldBase):
    description = "ListField store List of element"

    SPLIT_CHAR= ';'

    def __init__(self, *args, list_choices=None, **kwargs):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if list_choices is None:
            list_choices = []
        self.list_choices = list_choices

    def to_python(self, value):
        res = []
        if value is None:
            res = []

        if isinstance(value, list):
            res = value

        if isinstance(value, builtins.str):
            res = value.split(self.SPLIT_CHAR)
        try:
            if "[" in value and "]" in value:
                res = eval(value)
        except:
            pass
        return res

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None or value == "":
            return None
        res = self.SPLIT_CHAR.join(value)
        return res

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return self.get_prep_value(value)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=self.list_choices)
```

Then create List field like this one.

```
from django.db import 
class News(models.Model)
     heading=models.CharField(max_length=50)
     post_date=models.DateTimeField('Date Posted')
     labels=ListField()
```

Comment: Then, how do you store or retrieve data using this?